# What is the difference between O(x+y) and O(x*y)? What do either of them mean?

Tags: mapreduce, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

As far as I understand O(x+y) = O(bigger of the two). Am I right? What about O(x*y).

I was reading the mapreduce paper and it said `the master must make O(M + R) scheduling decisions and keeps O(M  R) state in memory`

I did not get that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between O(m+n) and O(mn)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896399/difference-between-omn-and-omn)

Comment: Yes thank you. That question was not suggested when I was writing the question.